# iBeacons: distance between bluetooth devices in iOS

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios8, ibeacon

I am working on an app that displays notification when user enters a particular area and exits from the area.
I am using 3 beacons for my app. When user is in between second and third Beacon I need to notify the user that he is inside the premises and when user has crossed the first beacon I need to notify him that he is outside the premises.
Till some extent I am able to achieve this by using the beacons accuracy property as distance between the user's device and all three beacons, but the time to display an alert to the user is more about 30 sec to one minute, but it should be instant.

Comment: Your question is not precise !! Please explain your exact problem..

Comment: My premises size is 20m. This distance is divided in the ratio of 3:5 so as to place beacons. One beacon is kept at the premise entrance, second and third at the distance of 7m and 13m from the first beacon (so that the ratio between devices is of 3:5). Now, I am walking from my entrance towards the third beacon, so as soon as the user is in between second and third device I want give user the message that he is inside and when user walks from second/third beacon towards first beacon and crosses it, I want user to get the message that he is outside the premises.

Comment: You need to assign proper Major-Minor values to Beacons and start programming app accordingly.

Comment: I am using the default major and minor value for the beacons  and comparing the distance (Accuracy) of device from beacons in the following delegate mehod:- 

(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)beaconRegion

 and trying to display the message. Inside message is shown correctly but outside message is not displayed.

Comment: the logic that i have implemented is:
  if (distacnceOfBeacon2 < distacnceOfBeacon1 && distacnceOfBeacon1 >= ((3/8)*totalDistance) ) {)
            [alertInside show];
    }
    else if (distacnceOfBeacon2 < distacnceOfBeacon3 && distacnceOfBeacon2 >= ((3/8)*totalDistance) && distacnceOfBeacon3 >= ((5/8)*totalDistance))
                [alertOutside show];
        }

Comment: Can you add some code of that part where you are showing alert?

Comment: The code used to display the alert is:
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)beaconRegion{if (distacnceOfBeacon2 < distacnceOfBeacon1 && distacnceOfBeacon1 >= ((3/8)*totalDistance) ) { 
   //show inside alert
        }
    }
    else if (distacnceOfBeacon2 < distacnceOfBeacon3 && distacnceOfBeacon2 >= ((3/8)*totalDistance) && distacnceOfBeacon3 >= ((5/8)*totalDistance)){
            //show outside alert
    }}

where distance1 ,distance2 & distance3 are accuracy values of beacon 1 2 & 3 respectively

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that **the `CLBeacon` `accuracy` property**, which gives you a distance estimate in meters, **lags by up to 20 seconds** behind a moving mobile device.  The same is true with the `proximity` property, which is derived from `accuracy`.  This lag may be causing the delays you describe.

Why does this lag exist?  Distance estimates are based on the bluetooth signal strength (`rssi` property) which varies a lot with radio noise.  In order to filter this noise, iOS uses a 20 second running average in calculating the distance estimate.  As a result, it tells you how far a beacon was away (on average) during the last 20 second period.

For applications where you need less lag in your estimate, you can use the `rssi` property directly.  But be aware that due to noise, you will get a much less accurate indication of your distance to a beacon from a single reading.

Read more here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/12/04/fundamentals-of-beacon-ranging.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). This information regarding lagging up to 20 seconds helped me. I have added a timer which fires every 10 seconds so that my logic for calculating the distance from the beacons runs after every 10 seconds. Now, my problem is that since this delegate method is called every second and logic runs every 10 seconds it displays the alert in every run, but it should be as, when user enters show the in message after that when moved out display out message and then when again moves in display in and so on.

Comment: Is there anyway by which I can restrict the call of delegate method so that it is called after some specific time period ?

Comment: The delegate gets called every second, but you can add logic to *ignore* the call if you have already processed ranging data, say within the last 10 secs.

Comment: I have added a timer which fires every 7 seconds so the logic to calculate the distance is processed after 7 seconds and not at every call of delegate method, but it is not helping to solve the problem as user is in motion and it may be the case that after moving out that timer is fired and user will receive alert after 7 seconds or he may be inside the premises and timer is fired at that the condition might match (as accuracy value is not exact distance) and alert is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 questions you are trying to ask here. Will try to address them seperately.

1. To notify when you are in between 2 beacons - This should be pretty straightforward to do using "accuracy" and/or the "proximity" property of both the beacons.
   If you need a closer estimate, use distance. pseudo code -

   ```
   beaconsRanged:(CLBeacon)beacon{
      if(beacon==BEACON1 && beacon.accuracy > requiredDistanceForBkn1)
          "BEACON 1 IN REQUIRED RANGE"
      if(beacon==BEACON2 && beacon.accuracy > requiredDistanceForBkn2)
          "BEACON 2 IN REQUIRED RANGE"
      }
   ```

   Whenever both the conditions are satisfied, you will be done. Use proximity if you don't want fine tuning.

Code tip - you can raise LocalNotifications when each of these conditions are satisfied and have a separate class which will observe the notifications and perform required operation.

2. Time taken to raise alert when condition is satisfied -  Ensure that you are raising alert on the **main thread**. If you do so on any other thread it takes a lot of time. I have tried the same thing and it just takes around a second to raise a simple alert. 
   One way I know of to do this -

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      //code
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Prad for the reply. Everything is woking on main thread, I have not created any separate thread. I think time to display he alert is more because didRangeBeacon: method is called once every second and beacon region has 3 beacons. So can it be the case that looping  and comparision of distances is taking time. Ideally it should not be the case according to my  understanding.